# Missing GWT Trait

Tags: scala, specs2

The GWT trait seems to be missing:

[image]

I checked the external dependencies and it doesn't seem to be there:

[image]

I'm using the following version of `specs2`:

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.1" % "test"
```

Is it in a different location? I'm not sure how to get it in order to use full support for GWT tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `specs2-gwt` to your build. See [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.1/org.specs2.guide.Installation.html#other-dependencies) for a list of all the additional specs2 jars.